# Character Encoding Issue while generating XML File with UTF-8

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

When I try to generate XML File using PHP with below mention tag then it doesn't allowing to generate xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

When i try to generate using encoding="ISO-8859-1" then only it allows but when i use encoding = "ISO-8859-1" then it prints some funny characters like Ã¢Â on behalf of single(') and double quotes(").

Please let me know how to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure it out with these provided information. Maybe you could use the [Marshal XML Serializer](https://github.com/Kingson-de/marshal-xml-serializer) to get around the issue.